# find the good number--an online code challenge

Tags: algorithm

Given a range: [a, b]，find all the good numbers in this range. The definition of  good number is that the number of this number's prime factor is also a prime number.

For example:
input: range [1 10]
good number: 6, 10

I can only come out a straightforward solution which check each element in the range. Is there any better one?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would 9 not be a good number?  Or any other in the [1..10] range?

Comment: I guess it should be "number of distinct prime factors is prime".

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a solution using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). if a number is prime all of its multiple will have this as a prime factor. This way you can calculate number of distinct prime factors of each number in range [1 n]. After that just check whether count of factors of number is a prime number itself.

```
const int N=100;
int factors[N]; // will store number of prime factors of each number in [1..n]
for(int i=2; i<=N; i++) {
    if(factors[i]==0) {  // we haven't found any factor of i yet so its prime
        for(int j=i; j<=N; j+=i) {
            factors[j]++;
        }
    }
}

int result=0;
for(int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
    int numOfFactors=factors[i];
    if(factors[numOfFactors]==1) {
        result++; // count will have value 1 only if its a prime number
    }
}
```